# Performance impact of running stored procedures in jobs

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

At work, I have come across several SQL Server stored procedures that are only used by a single job. In that case, wouldn't it just make more sense to run the code in a job step? Is there some benefit from running statements in stored procedures?

These specific stored procedures do not require input variables, nor are they commonly used calculations; they are mostly just complex select statements. Looking for advice on best practice and performance impact.

Comment: Stored procedure will cache the execution plan and it will be faster than run query individually

Comment: Will the job not cache the execution plan?

Comment: The plan will be cached in both cases.

Comment: Other potential reasons for favoring wrapping logic in a stored procedure include: (1) source control and configuration management purposes, (2) ease of executing the process outside of the scheduler, including for testing and performance analysis, (3) visibility - a developer may have access to view and maintain a stored procedure, but not have easy access to the scheduled job that runs it.

Comment: Have you ever tried to _edit_ T-SQL code in the job step editor? (Other points are valid too, of course. But that one's a deal-breaker for me.)

Comment: Don't fix things that are not broken - EVER! Did you ask anyone else why this situation exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no material performance difference.

Code in a stored procedure is stored in the user database, present in backups, owned by the database owner, and can be invoked and debugged from anywhere.

Code in a job step is stored in the MSDB system database and owned by the job owner and can only be run through Agent.